# How to divide the space between three columns with div tag?

Tags: php, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I have created three columns like this:

```
<div style="float: left">Left Column</div>
<div style="float: left">Middle Column</div>
<div style="float: left">Right Column</div>
```

This works well on its own. However the moment I add it to my Wordpress page template, by defining a left and right column around the existing main column something unexpected happens:

http://venuscloud.com/crm-software/

The left column is correctly placed and the middle column is as expected in the middle but the right column is at the bottom.  I don't understand why the remaining space is not divided between the three columns as expected.

Any comments?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your divs are. The right and left divs have css floats. But your middle div doesn'r have that attributes. Its keep on middle with margin-attributes. Even giving float to middle div won't help you. Because then you have to make the op divs correct.

One method you can do is, change your divs order like :

```
<div id="left_column"></div>
<div id="right_column"></div>
<div class=​"col-full"></div>
```

then add `float:right` to your `right-column div`.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Hi Sabari, Many thanks, your solution seems almost to be working. Now the middle and right columns are perfectly aligned. But the left column is actually a row and slightly higher placed. Why is that?

Comment: Oh right, it seems the left column also needs style="float: left". I will test it more tonight and set the answer. many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now but my guess is you have padding or margins set on the divs, which makes the total width >100% for the three of them combined.